# Running uwsgi with virtualenv and flask

Tags: python, flask, debian, uwsgi

When trying to run my flask application I get the error:

```
uwsgi no module named site
```

I created a configuration file as such:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:8000
processes = 4
virtualenv = /var/www/test/venv
chdir = /var/www/test
module = run
callable = manager
logto = var/www/uwsgi.log
```

The location of my run.py is /var/www/test/run.py with the following code:

```
from flask.ext.migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask.ext.script import Manager
from app import app, db

if __name__ == "__main__":
    migrate = Migrate(app, db)
    manager = Manager(app)
    manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)
    manager.run()
```

Can anyone help me understand where I have gone wrong please? I am running a system wide UWSGI.

**EDIT**

I installed uwsgi and virtualenv using pip and I have the following versions:

- uWSGI==2.0.2
- virtualenv==1.11.4

My system wide python version (and the one inside my venv) is: Python 2.7.3

Comment: generally that error is a sign that your virtualenv has been built for a different python version than the one used by uWSGI

Comment: Thank you very much for the help @roberto . I added more information to my question, does that help shed any light on the problem?

Comment: @roberto people tell me to use the no-site option but this seems like a bit of a bodge

Comment: no-site is a really advanced trick, nothing you should care about generally (and generally it is a bad advice). Check the python version uWSGI is using, it is printed in its startup logs.

Comment: @roberto Thank you again for your help. Here is the read out: Python version: 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 14:09:21)  [GCC 4.7.2]                                   
Set PythonHome to /var/www/app/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want use app.run() (or manager.run()) and uwsgi at the same time, because:

- app.run()/manager.run() launch a developpment server ([Flask doc, Watch Out](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/uwsgi/), [Flask doc app.run()](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.run))
- uwsgi is a already a server

So you just need to properly setup uwsgi, something like that should work:

```
app-name   = test 

pidfile    = /run/uwsgi/%(app-name)/pid
socket     = /run/uwsgi/%(app-name)/socket

logto      = /var/log/uwsgi/%(app-name).log
log-date   = true

processes  = 4
plugins    = http,python

base       = /srv/www/%(app-name)
home       = %(base)/venv # http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#home-virtualenv-venv-pyhome
pythonpath = %(base)/venv # http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#pythonpath-python-path-pp

module     = app 
callable   = app

chdir      = %(base)
```